# Conditional variable assignment

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm doing this in one of my templates:

```
{% if activite.travel %}
    {% with activite.travel.personne as personne %}

        {% include 'includes/person_detail.html' %}

    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
{% if activite.relation %}
    {% with activite.relation.src as personne %}

        {% include 'includes/person_detail.html' %}

    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Note: I may have more fields to come in `activite` that's why I'm not doing "`else`" but two separate "`if`".

I'd like to do something like:

```
{% if activite.travel %}
    {% set personne=activite.travel.personne %}
{% elsif activite.relation %}
    {% set personne=activite.relation.src %}
{% endif %}
{% include 'includes/person_detail.html' %}
```

Is there a way to do this *in the template*?

Comment: Have a look at [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). You'll be able to move a lot of the logic into Python code. You should be able to simplify the template to something like `{% person_detail activite %}` (which helps with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896088/best-practice-for-include-templates) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly... but you can use `with` inside of [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% if activite.travel %}
    {% include 'includes/person_detail.html' with personne=activite.travel.personne %}
{% elif activite.relation %}
    {% include 'includes/person_detail.html' with personne=activite.relation.src %}
{% endif %}
```